# Sprite Kit - Remove SKNode based on NSMutableArray list of Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am having a bit of trouble removing all nodes whos name/ID is in my NSMutableArray.
I have set the value for each object to be a unique name. So I can delete only the ones that are in the NSMutableArray.

The objects are created in a loop with the name of each being unique.

Like so:

```
    myObject.name = @"8dAN3kgh6E";
```

next loop

```
    myObject.name = @"WsFkdGrmHm";
```

next loop

```
    myObject.name = @"ov5BjzHGiw";
```

These values are then added and stored in an array.

NSMutableArray *currentShapeArray

```
(
    8dAN3kgh6E,
    WsFkdGrmHm,
    ov5BjzHGiw
)
```

I then  loop through the currentShapeArray, which I do like so:

```
for (NSString *myObjectNames in currentShapeArray) {

      NSLog(@"%@", myObjectNames); //works and gives each value correctly
}
```

But for the life of me I cannot seem to figure out how to at this point remove the object that contains that specfic node.name.

Similar to  [myObject removeFromParent]; ...but I need to select based on myObject.name property.

I am sure it is something simple, and hopefully someone can give me a nudge in the right direction. Thanks!

**UPDATE: 1.**

I tried what was suggested by sangony, for some reason it gives me the the following error when I use it.

```
2014-05-07 23:11:56.163 dotmatcher[1149:60b] NODE NAME: FY7opRB1Wk
2014-05-07 23:11:56.164 dotmatcher[1149:60b] ButtonTmp 1
2014-05-07 23:11:56.164 dotmatcher[1149:60b] Previous 1
2014-05-07 23:11:56.164 dotmatcher[1149:60b] -[__NSCFString name]: unrecognized selector    sent to instance 0xee1fe50
2014-05-07 23:11:56.167 dotmatcher[1149:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught     exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString name]: unrecognized selector     sent to instance 0xee1fe50'


- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint loc = [touch locationInNode:self];
NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:loc];

for (SKNode *node in nodes) {

    NSString *tmp = node.name;
    if (tmp.length !=0) {
        NSLog(@"ended");

        NSString *buttonTmp = [node.userData objectForKey:@"buttonType"];

        if ([buttonTmp isEqualToString:@"1"] && [previousButton isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            endButton = @"1";


            NSLog(@"NODE NAME: %@",node.name);
            NSLog(@"ButtonTmp %@", buttonTmp);
            NSLog(@"Previous %@", previousButton);

            NSMutableArray *discardedItems = [NSMutableArray array];
            for(SKNode *object in currentShapeArray)
            {
                if([object.name isEqualToString:node.name])
                {
                    [object removeFromParent]; // not sure if you need this or not
                    [discardedItems addObject:object];
                }
            }
            [currentShapeArray removeObjectsInArray:discardedItems];


            NSLog(@"ButtonID: %@",[node.userData objectForKey:@"buttonID"]);
            NSLog(@"ButtonType: %@",[node.userData objectForKey:@"buttonType"]);
            NSLog(@"ButtonColumn: %@",[node.userData objectForKey:@"buttonColumn"]);
            NSLog(@"ButtonRow: %@",[node.userData objectForKey:@"buttonRow"]);

            NSLog(@"AFTER REMOVE%@",currentShapeArray);

        }

    }
}
}
}
```

**UPDATE 2** This was the final code to get it working. Thank you Sangony!

```
NSMutableArray *discardedItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for(SKNode *object in currentShapeArray)
{
        [object removeFromParent]; 
        [discardedItems addObject:object];

}
[currentShapeArray removeObjectsInArray:discardedItems];
```

Comment: it would be a lot simpler to just store the nodes in the array, or even better if you can add them all to the same node and no other nodes to it so that you can use that node's children array as your storage and be able to use enumerateChildNodes...

Comment: @LearnCocos2D what are the advantages of doing it that way instead of the way mentioned by sangony?

Comment: Because you get the "get by name" and enumeration with name for free, and no extra storage needed, no extra code to add/remove nodes to a custom array in order to keep it in sync, and thus fewer potential coding bugs.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I see.... looks like I have a small part to recode :) Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
NSMutableArray *discardedItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for(SKNode *object in currentShapeArray)
{
    if([object.name isEqualToString:node.name])
    {
        [object removeFromParent]; // not sure if you need this or not
        [discardedItems addObject:object];
    }
}
[currentShapeArray removeObjectsInArray:discardedItems];
```

Comment: thank you for the help, I have tried what you suggested, but Now it is crashing on me. I have updated my question please have a look if you have the time. Thank you.

Comment: @user3450888 - In the line if([object.name isEqualToString:node.name]), did you modify it to suit your needs? In other words, what's the object you want to remove from the array?

Comment: I am trying to remove any node(s) from its parent(column1/column2 etc) that has the same "node.name" that is found within the NSMutableArray currentShapeArray. So wouldn't object be this, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @user3450888 - I suggest you check the array's content. Put a NSLog(@"%@", currentShapeArray); right after the NSLog(@"Previous %@", previousButton); line so you can see the array content.

Comment: I did that, it gives me the list of node.name's that I saved to the array each as a NSString.... Do I need to save the SKNode to the array instead? I am still not sure why it is causing it to crash.

Comment: @user3450888 - Bingo! I think that's were the issue is. I think you are right on with your suggestion, try saving the SKNode to the array instead of just the name. Remember that the line if([object.name isEqualToString:node.name]) is checking the NODE's name and it's expecting to find a node and not just a NSString.

Comment: I saved it as a SKNode, it now does not crash. The only last issue is it only deletes the last SKNode, or rather the button that the touch is over when touch end is triggered. I need it to loop through and remove all in that list from the parent. not just the one.

Comment: @user3450888 - That is more of a game logic issue. You will have to look at your code and modify it as to do what you need it to do. Remember that you are comparing the object.name to the node.name so depending on your code structure, you might have to run it several times with new node.name values. I don't know your code so I cannot give you any help with that. But you know now how to delete objects from your array based on node.name now so that should get you to the finish.

Comment: sangony - Thank you for your time :) I will update the code in the question when I figure it out 100% so others can learn from this :) Cheers.